# In springboot-oauth2-client, What is the base address of Token URL?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm studying spring boot and I'm not very good at it.
Anyway, I make google oauth2 authorization using springboot oauth2 client
It works in the following way:

1. /oauth2/authorization/google (springboot oauth2 client's base google auth address)
2. google login
3. /login/oauth2/code/google (springboot oauth2 client's base google redirect address)
4. authorization finish

So I made google oauth2 authorization, and try to use it at https://console.actions.google.com/ 's account linking
[image]

I know Authorization URL is /oauth2/authorization/google, because it is springboot oauth2 client's base google auth address.
But I don't know what url to put in TOKEN URL.

Comment: The token url is the Same aus the auth url. Just place /token instead of /auth at the end of the url

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

and you can do some practise here too.

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/